# Search for the next instance in array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, search, optimization

```
For i = 1 To max
    matchFoundIndex = Application.Match(arr(i), arr, 0)
Next
```

The above code returns the first occurrence of `arr(i)` in `arr`. However, there can be other instances of `arr(i)` in `arr`. In short, how can I efficiently find such next instances of `arr(i)` in `arr` (avoiding the classic n^2 loop)?

Comment: I would recommend building a scripting dictionary.

Comment: Any pointers on the implementation?

Comment: Isn't that loop going to find all of the matches albeit some in reverse? If arr(2) and arr(8) are the same then arr(2) will be located when i is 8.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with VBA, but in general if you're trying to find all indices for every element in an array, you could use a map (or dictionary), and iterate through the array while adding each index to the corresponding value's entry in the dictionary. So if you have `[2, 3, 2, 4]` you'd end up with `{ 2: [0, 2], 3: [1], 4: [3] }` (value `2` is in indices `0` and `2`, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could "hide" every match found and keep using `Application.Match()`:

```
Function GetIndexes(arr As Variant) As String
    Dim tempArr As Variant, matchIndex As Variant, element As Variant
    Dim matchIndexes As String

    tempArr = arr ' use a temporary array not to spoil the passed one
    For Each element In tempArr
        If element <> "|||" Then 'skip elements already marked as "already found"
            matchIndexes = ""
            matchIndex = Application.Match(element, tempArr, 0) 'search for array element matching current one
            Do
                matchIndexes = matchIndexes & matchIndex & " "
                tempArr(matchIndex - 1) = "|||" 'mark found array element as "already found"
                matchIndex = Application.Match(element, tempArr, 0) 'search for next array element matching current one
            Loop While Not IsError(matchIndex) ' loop until no occurrences of current array element
            GetIndexes = GetIndexes & "element '" & element & "' found at indexes: " & Replace(Trim(matchIndexes), " ", ",") & vbCrLf
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

which you could exploit as follows:

```
Sub main()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Array("a1", "a2", "a3", "a1", "a2", "a3")

    MsgBox GetIndexes(arr)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of this code? Also, what is the worst and average case time complexity of excel function Match?

Comment: i actually don't know both answers. But with my code you _explicitly_ (i.e. eith `For Each element In tempArr` loop) iterate through array elements only once and then have `Application.Match` do the rest of the work.